# Errors within nested views always show a vague error message. Can it be made more verbose?

Tags: exception, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using View Composers and nested views in general to build my layouts, and whenever any PHP errors are encountered, it always shows a generic `Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception` error message. Is there a way for it to show the actual error without having to guess what it is? Or is this limitation of PHP impossible to get around?

The error log also shows the same vague message, so that isn't a solution either.

Comment: Maybe not but post your code, this may happen because of undefined variables or any kind of error in the view.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha yeah I'm talking about any errors like that. If there's a syntax error or undefined variable in the nested view, the error will always be `:__toString() must not throw an exception` instead of "Undefined variable $variable". I want it to show the actual error. Does that make sense?

Comment: Have you turned on `debug` using `debug => true` in `app/config/app.php` file ?

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha I found what the problem was while trying to create a replication of the issue to show you. This whole time I've been using `{{ View::make('nested.view') }}` within my views to render the nested views. If the view had an error it gave the message above. Changing it to `@include('nested.view')` solves the issue for me. Thanks for the help anyway!